# case within a select case in mysql

Tags: mysql, case, nested

I'm getting sick of trying to hook up to MSSQL, so I'm switching over to mysql. 
It's slow progress. Here's my current stumper: 
mssql:

```
create function W(m varchar(255)) returns int begin

declare @e int
set @e = (select COUNT(N) from P where N = m)

declare @t int
set @t = dbo.C(m)

return case @t 
when 0 then -1 
when 1 then
    case @e when 0 then -1 else 1 end
when 2 then
    case @e when 1 then -1 when 2 then 0 when 3 then 0 when 4 then 1 end
when 3 then 
    case @e when 1 then -1 when 2 then 1 end
when 4 then 
    case @e when 1 then -1 when 2 then 0 when 3 then 1 end
end
end
```

I'd like to switch this to mysql. Is there a  valid mysql way to:

```
select select case n when 0 then 1 when 1 then 2 end into var
```

?
How about

```
set var = select case n when [...] end
```

?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will guide you in using [Inline IF and CASE statements in MySQL](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1335105421-Inline-IF-and-CASE-statements-in-MySQL)

Snippet:

```
SELECT CASE num_heads
           WHEN 0 THEN 'Zombie'
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Human'
           ELSE 'Alien'
       END AS race
FROM user
```

or

```
mysql> SET @val := CASE num_heads
                       WHEN 0 THEN 'Zombie'
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'Human'
                       ELSE 'Alien'
                   END AS race;

mysql> SELECT @val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
SET @var := CASE n WHEN [...] END;
```

?

(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)